# End while loop for character substitution

Tags: c++, for-loop, encryption

This is taken out from Keyshanc Encryption Algorithm. https://github.com/Networc/keyshanc

My question is: How can I possibly manipulate this main method for having multiple encryption outputs with the keys chosen from the password array?

I am not able to break out of the encoding loop right at the end.

```
int main()
{
    string password[] = {"JaneAusten", "MarkTwain", "CharlesDickens", "ArthurConanDoyle"};

    for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        char keys[95];

        keyshanc(keys, password[i]); 

        char inputChar, trueChar=NULL;
        cout << "Enter characters to test the encoding; enter # to quit:\n";
        cin>>inputChar;

        for (int x=0; x < 95; ++x)
        {
            if (keys[x] == inputChar)
            {
                trueChar = char(x+32);
                break;
            }
        }

        while (inputChar != '#')
        {
            cout<<trueChar;
            cin>>inputChar;
            for (int x=0; x < 95; ++x)
            {
                if (keys[x] == inputChar)
                {
                    trueChar = char(x+32);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking input in two places, so you have to put two tests.

When you are in the `while` loop, you have to break out of the `while` loop, and also break out of the `for(;;)` loop. You can set `i=5;` to force the `for(;;)` loop to stop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; ++i)
{
    char inputChar, trueChar = 0;
    cout << "Enter characters to test the encoding; enter # to quit:\n";

    cin >> inputChar;

    if (inputChar == '#') //<== ADD THIS
        break;

    while (inputChar != '#')
    {
        cout << trueChar;
        cin >> inputChar;

        if (inputChar == '#') //<== ADD THIS to break out of for(;;) loop
        {
            i = 5;
        }

    }
}
```

In addition `trueChar` and `inputChar` should be initialized to `0` not `NULL` (although it's the same thing in this). Don't print `trueChar` if it's not initialized.

```
if (trueChar)
    cout << trueChar;
```